# xamarin studio stops debugging

Tags: debugging, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I'm using xamarin studio and monotouch for developing iphone applications. When I set break points on my code and start debugging with the xamarin studio, the debugger breaks the codes on the break point correctly, but the problem is that when I trace the codes with debugger after some seconds ( maybe 30-40 sec) the debugger stops debugging, just like a crash. What should I do?

**EDIT**

I noticed that it is not because of the break point. Whenever I do not work with the phone after a few seconds the debugger disconnect and stop debugging. Is this really a bug? I think maybe there is a setting that if I change it then the issue will be fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a bug, verify if there is a newer release and update you copy.
Otherwise, report it to  the software providers for a solution.

Comment: it isn't a bug. It is a feature to kill hanging apps on the Phone. If it didn't do it your phone could easily become unusable this answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this done by the iOS operating system??? doesn't it only give you ~30 seconds to return from the first event otherwise it kills the application process ? So if you sit in the debugger then it will kill that too?

Comment: Thank for your reply @anthony. this problems accrues every where. Even if I am in the second screen or Third screen from my application and as you said the time is for first event.

Comment: Can this be deactivated? Debugging this way is almost Impossible.

Comment: It doesn't happen after the App first returns control back to the operating system. I don't think it happens in the emulator either. Debug that code there.